# Estimating power usage of idle motor

Tags: power, motor, induction-motor

I would like to calculate the power usage of an idle motor. The motor drives state a power usage of approx 8-10% of full load.

Would it simply be the case of taking 8-10% of the motor's power rating (in kW) and multiplying by the number of hours to obtain the kWh usage?

Also, I've been told that the 8-10% power usage at idle allows the motor to start up much faster? I've tried researching but haven't found anything stating this..

Comment: What do you mean by "Idle Motor" ?  Is it stalled with current applied? Is it rotating with no load (ie. de-clutched)?

Comment: My understanding is that the motor is stationary, but just enough current is being applied to create the magnetic fields without turning. When it is desired to turn the motor, the magnetic field is already established, thus decreases the time taken for the motor to start. Does this make sense or have I been given the wrong information?

Comment: And what kind of motor? DC or AC? And if AC, single phase or polyphase?

Comment: I am curious what equipment you are using to apply such a small amount of power to a motor, that it is magnetised but not turning.

Comment: It is a three phase AC motor. There is a large amount of inertia to overcome and I believe this is the reason for the 8-10% of power.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume "power usage of idle motor" would be if it were running full-speed, no-load. Motors generally consume a large current for a short time to spin up. Since most larger AC motors are typically 85-92% efficient at converting electricity into mechanical work, 8-10% loss seems reasonable, including bearing friction and windage. Start-up speed depends on load and motor type (AC induction, capacitor-start, synchronous, DC, etc.) While they do generally start faster with no load, synchronous AC motors feature very fast start-up time (but generally lower efficiencies.) High-inertia loads can be problematic for some motors, as they use a special "start-winding" which is designed to work for only a split second.

Answer (score 0):

Think you better takes the total KWh from your facilitie wattmeter ,and DIVIDES it by  the total hours of measure.The total KWh consumed is given generally by a multiplier in the wattmeter itself,and is obtaining easily from internet .
This is the neat KW of your motor at your given load,or even ANY mechanical load ,include  completely idle.

thanks
from   Brazil

Answer (score 0):

In motors power is mostly matter of definitions. In modern servo drives the power wasted by the drive itself is function of current, because it's switching output stage that only wastes Rdson*I*I or Vf*I. So it's not directly related to motor power, more to motor torque.

Normally when they talk about efficiency, they mean percents of rated power. And they can only calculate or measure power of the drive, because losses on motors may vary.